# Run program at Windows 7 boot without user logging in

Tags: windows, windows-7

It's very unclear from the documentation I've found - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx
for instance
whether HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
will run on OS boot, or will only run when any user logs in (but not a specific user like with HKCU key).

I need to run a program without anyone logging in on boot. What's the way to do this with Windows 7 x64 SP1?

Comment: The run and runonce keys are launched on login event. Runonce will be executed once then removed after execution. You should create a scheduled task via the task scheduler that is set to run on boot.

Comment: As well to have something only run once in task scheduler disable it as one of the actions, ex `schtasks /Change /TN "\Adobe Acrobat Update Task" /DISABLE`.

Comment: create a scheduled task which runs at start: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7